# How to get a handle of Task when it is awaited

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

```
// This does not work
Task t = await Task.Run(async () => { await requestThread.Execute(); }, cts.Token);

// This does work
Task t = Task.Run(async () => { await requestThread.Execute(); }, cts.Token);
```

When I try the above (with await) I get error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

What is the proper way of getting a handle to the task returned by Task.Run?

The Execute method definition looks like this:

```
public async Task Execute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to await a object the same line it is created, it is perfectly fine to do

```
Task t = Task.Run(async () => { await requestThread.Execute(); }, cts.Token);
await t;
```

Now you have a reference to `t` and it has been awaited till completion.

---

BTW, I find it very odd you are wrapping a async task in a `Task.Run`, does the async method have a large synchronous part at the start before it awaits internally? If it does not you should likely just do

```
Task t = requestThread.Execute();
await t;
```

Comment: I was totally over-thinking it... This works and it is so much cleaner.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey Scott, inside my Execute method I make a HttpRequest to a REST web service.  Would you say that is a good motivation for wrapping the Execute method in a `Task.Run` ?  You can find more of the code here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136243/task-run-proper-use

Comment: I would make `SendRequest` async too and await that in the method. Then there is no need to do the `Task.Run`

Comment: Okay I did this and it works great, thanks!  However, another question arose.  So in order to make `SendRequest()` async, I replaced `request.GetResponse()` with `request.GetResponseAsync()` and awaited that. Let's suppose though that inside `SendRequest()` I was calling a custom method that is not an async, and I want to make it an async, how would I go about that? Would I add an `await Task.Run(some code in a lambda)` inside the method I'm trying to make async?

Comment: No, it is not good to "fake" being async. Just put in the documentation that your function has a large synchronous part, then let the caller decide if they are ok with the function blocking for a little bit before returning the task. If they are ok with it they can call your function and no extra overhead is introduced, if they are not ok with it they can call Task.Run before they run the function like how your code currently does. The key takeaway is you let the caller decide if they want to make a new thread or not, if they are already on the background thread they may not need to do one.

Comment: By the way, you really should be passing in `cts.Token` in to `Execute` then passing it along to `GetResponseAsync`, the way you have it now the only thing the token is doing for you is if the task was canceled before you ever started the method it would never call `Execute`.

Comment: Actually I had the token passed into execute. If you go to the link from a few comments ago, you can see my code for `Execute` (although I was not passing it, it was just global which I changed now).  I was using it is for my `Task.Delay` inside execute, but further passing it on to `SendRequest()` is a good idea in case it is cancelled before making the request.